# lxml.cssselect CSSSelector doesn't support attributes

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

I'm trying to parse HTML pages and get items with specific attributes. I'm using [`lxml.cssselect`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) for the job.

I can't seem to get it to work with attribute selector. The following selector: `p[itemprop="articleBody"]` returns nothing on [this page](http://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/man-jail-writing-racist-graffiti-refugees-homes-33488053) for example. Using the same selector from Firefox or Chrome works.

When I try selectors with no attributes, they do work.

I create the CSSSelector with the `html` translator.

Is this kind of selector simply not supported by lxml.cssselect? I couldn't find any reference to it in the docs.

Comment: Would you mind posting your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have expertise with `lxml.cssselect` (I've had a quick go and can't even set up the element tree, so have been unable to replicate your exact problem). However, I have had success using an equivalent `lxml` method that may be of use to you.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/man-jail-writing-racist-graffiti-refugees-homes-33488053'
page = requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
p_elements = tree.cssselect('p[itemprop="articleBody"]')
print(p_elements)
```

**Output:**

```
[<Element p at 0xa503ae8>,
 <Element p at 0xa503db8>,
 <Element p at 0xa503bd8>,
 <Element p at 0xa54b1d8>,
 <Element p at 0xa54b0e8>,
 <Element p at 0xa54b138>,
 <Element p at 0xa54b188>]
```

Generally, when using `lxml` I find that selecting elements by XPath is far more flexible than by CSS selector.

Comment: ARGH! This is someone else's code I'm working on. Turns out they used lxml.html.clean.clean_html to clean the HTML. The default behavior (which they used) is to drop all 'unsafe' attributes, including this one.